# Multi-index pandas update

Tags: pandas

Have two dataframes df1 and df2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

A = list(range(3,9))
B = [datetime.date(2019,1,1), datetime.date(2019,1,3), datetime.date(2019,1,2), datetime.date(2019,1,8), datetime.date(2017,6,2), datetime.date(2011,5,6)]
C = list('abcdef')
D = list('LMNOPQ')
E = list(range(5,11))

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D, 'E': E})

a = list(range(3,7))
b = [datetime.date(2010,1,1), datetime.date(2019,1,3), datetime.date(2019,1,2), datetime.date(2010,2,10)]
c = list('xymb')
d = list('GZYP')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c, 'D': d})
```

Row Index 1 and 2 have the same Columns 'A' and 'B'.

What is the best way to update df1 with df2 data for Columns 'C' and 'D'?

```
df3 = df1.set_index(['A', 'B']).update(df2.set_index(['A', 'B']))
```

...doesn't work

Expected output is:

```
    A   B           C   D   E
0   3   2019-01-01  a   L   5
1   4   2019-01-03  y   Z   6
2   5   2019-01-02  m   Y   7
3   6   2019-01-08  d   O   8
4   7   2017-06-02  e   P   9
5   8   2011-05-06  f   Q   10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is work , just need separated lines , since update will change the original df , assign is not needed.

```
df1=df1.set_index(['A', 'B'])
df1.update(df2.set_index(['A', 'B']))
df1=df1.reset_index()
df1
   A          B  C  D   E
0  3 2019-01-01  a  L   5
1  4 2019-01-03  y  Z   6
2  5 2019-01-02  m  Y   7
3  6 2019-01-08  d  O   8
4  7 2017-06-02  e  P   9
5  8 2011-05-06  f  Q  10
```